# Publish fails with: dotnet build exited with code 0 (Azure Data Studio - SQL Database Projects extension)

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I'm trying to Publish a database project with Azure Data Studio (ADS) to an Azure SQL Database. The build of the .sqlproj works fine with Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.11.20) using SSDT, I always get the following output:

```
Build started...
------ Build started: Project: Database Extract, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        Database Extract -> C:\Users\Peter\Source\Repos\Azure DWH\Azure DWH\Database Extract\bin\Output\Database_Extract.dll
        Database Extract -> C:\Users\Peter\Source\Repos\Azure DWH\Azure DWH\Database Extract\bin\Output\Database Extract.dacpac
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Note: The project was originally build using SSDT.

So when I try to Publish the same .sqlproj-file, using the SQL Database Projects extension for ADS, the build starts off just fine, but always ends with the follwing error:

```
    stdout:     127 Warning(s)
    stdout:     0 Error(s)
    stdout: 
    stdout: Time Elapsed 00:00:03.65
    stdout: 
    >>> "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"  build "c:\\Users\\Peter\\source\\repos\\Azure DWH\\Azure DWH\\Database Extract\\Database Extract.sqlproj" /p:NetCoreBuild=true /p:NETCoreTargetsPath="c:\\Users\\Peter\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-mssql.sql-database-projects-vscode-0.19.0\\BuildDirectory"    … exited with code: 0
```

Apparantly the build succeedes because I see a lot of warnings related to incorrect case-referencing of columns and tables which I did not include here. The error is no more non-descriptive than "exited with code 0". The Publish task does not start though.

After some fooling around with creating a new database project from ADS using the existing database as it stands, I managed to get the Build and Publish task working, but of course I want to use the old .sqlproj-file.

Can someone please elaborate on this problem and maybe point me in the right direction so I can use the old project file for the Publish task?

I have tried the following things:

- Check the .NET SDK versions on my system, which are the following:

  - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\

    - 1.04
    - 3.1.426
    - 5.0.408
    - 5.0.413
    - 7.0.102
- Reinstalled (repaired) the .NET SDK's and pointed ADS to the SDK folder paths
- Installed an older version of the SQL Database Projects extension (current version is 0.20, tried it on 0.14)
- Tried the same Build-action on the same .sqlproj with VSCode (using extensions SQL Server (mssql) 1.16.0 and SQL Database Projects 0.19 and 0.20) (got the same error message)
- Updated the nuget.config file in C:\...\AppData\Roaming\NuGet with the following becasue of an earlier, different error:

  ```
  <configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Completely reinstalled ADS (deleted all preferences and extension folders as well)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I continued my research today and I stumbled across a GitHub page which clearly states I should edit the .sqlproj-file. I'm not sure if I had seen this before in my research, but for anyone still looking for an answer to this go ahead and edit your file as stated below, it should work:

https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/tree/main/src/Microsoft.Build.Sql